# WPF user control with an image inside does not resize

Tags: wpf, image, user-controls, resize

I have a user control that contains only an image. This image is computed in execution time. In behind there is a WritableBitMap where I do my ploting. Then the image.source is set to this WritableBitMap.
So my user control looks like:

```
public partial class ColorBrainMap : UserControl
{  
    //... some stuff
    //I load the base image from the resources
    BitmapImage tempImg = new BitmapImage();
    tempImg.BeginInit();
    tempImg.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ColorBrainMap;component/imgs/brain.png");
    tempImg.EndInit();

    //I copy the image into a WritableBitMap for convenience
    WriteableBitmap baseImage = new WriteableBitmap(tempImg);
    //I do some plotting over the base image
    //and set the final result as a source for the image
    image.Source = baseImage;
 }
```

In the other side my xaml is extremelly simple:

```
<Grid>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="image" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

The I create my new project. I add the component as a reference and drop a new instance into my xaml so it looks like that:

```
<Window x:Class bla bla 
    Height="396" Width="541" 
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:ColorBrainMapTOOL;assembly=ColorBrainMap">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="219*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <my:ColorBrainMap HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="brainMap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
      <!-- some other components in the other column of the grid-->
      </Grid>
</Window>
```

The whole thing works nicelly until I try to resize it. The control itself resizes (I tested it adding some background and border and the whole thing moves nicelly) but not the image. The image recalculates the plot on demand and works nice but it get stuck to it initial size.

Any clue of how to do it without resizing the internal images and recalculating the plots and all that work again ??

Comment: You are not setting Stretch="Fill" on the my:ColorBrainMap. Intentional?

Comment: There is not Stretch Property in the my:ColorBrainMap. Should it be there? Should ColorBrainMap inherit from image to have it?

Comment: For Image, the Stretch propery determines how the image should scale in its container (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.stretch.aspx). I am guessing the my:ColorBrainMap get placed in the grid?

Comment: @javirs The code and XAML of your ColorBrainMap control looks ok. The image should always fill the entire control. Please show us more of the XAML where you use the ColorBrainMap.

Comment: Nzc... I know what stretch does but the my:ColorBrainMap does not have the Stretch Property.
@Clemens I edited my question with further details on the tester project XAML but after testing I can see that the ColorBrainMap componenet does stretch and fills the while column in the grid so the problem should be inside the ColorBrainMap :S

Thanks you all for the support !

Comment: @javirs Then you should perhaps also post the whole ColorBrainMap XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a `ViewBox` and set your Image or the `ColorBrainMap` to be its Child;

Comment: I neeed to develop a WPF user control that people will drag and drop to their XAML. So I cannot work like that. Do you propose adding in my control a ViweBox with the image inside ?

Comment: MAN !!! It Works !!! :D

I really think that there must be other way to just ask your image to stretch himself but until other solution appears I will accept yours as it solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with binding:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ActualWidth}" Name="image" Stretch="Fill">
</Grid>
```

Comment: You might wanna try it with `AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}` instead of `AncestorType={x:Type Grid}`